# How to select nth element from the image grid in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuCkc.png)How to select and click on nth image from the grid?

I tried following code but its not working.

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[class='course_icon']"));
li.get(2).click();
```

I am getting Image list into Li but the click is not happening

Comment: Post the html (as text).

Answer (score 0):

If you sure your selector is true, please try following :

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[class='course_icon']"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(li.get(2)).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Hi, 
I f I dont use selector is there any other option that I can use like xpath ?

Comment: ofcourse, but you should provide us the html code. @Guru001

Answer (score 0):

Try using Javascript Executor:

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[class='course_icon']"));    
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", li.get(2));
```